pip install pytrec_eval fails with ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
I am trying to install pytrec_eval package using this command python -m pip install pytrec_eval but it fails with the following error: ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1133). I am trying to install it in a conda environment with python=3.9 on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 9.4.0).
Here is the log of the error:
Collecting pytrec_eval
  Using cached pytrec_eval-0.5.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [44 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
          h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1285, in request
          self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1331, in _send_request
          self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1280, in endheaders
          self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1040, in _send_output
          self.send(msg)
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 980, in send
          self.connect()
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1454, in connect
          self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 501, in wrap_socket
          return self.sslsocket_class._create(
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1074, in _create
          self.do_handshake()
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1343, in do_handshake
          self._sslobj.do_handshake()
      ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1133)
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-d8_09f0p/pytrec-eval_ea7e63f86646420cbfc12ae9c46aac88/setup.py", line 27, in <module>
          response = urllib.request.urlopen(REMOTE_TREC_EVAL_URI)
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
          return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
          response = self._open(req, data)
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
          result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
          result = func(*args)
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
          return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
        File "/home/myusername/miniconda3/envs/hipporag-py39/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
          raise URLError(err)
      urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1133)>
      Fetching trec_eval from https://github.com/usnistgov/trec_eval/archive/v9.0.8.tar.gz.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I am only getting the error with this package, not the remaining ones.

pytrec_eval is a Python interface to trec_eval. When it's being installed pytrec_eval downloads trec_eval from an URL written in its setup.py. You seem to have an HTTPS (SSL) problem with this URL. If you're at home — ask you provider. If you're in an enterprise — ask you admins. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+certificate+verify+failed%3A+self-signed+certificate+in+certificate+chain

@phd: indeed, I am in a company network. I ended up working it around to install it.

This is a workaround to install the package but does not solve the SSL certificate error problem.
I downloaded the pytrec_eval code from github and navigated to the project directory:
git clone https://github.com/cvangysel/pytrec_eval.git
cd pytrec_eval

Then, I downloaded trec_eval where pytrec_eval setup.py file fails to connect to:
grep https://github.com/usnistgov/trec_eval/archive/v9.0.8.tar.gz

I extracted the zip file to trec_eval directory:
tar -xvzf v9.0.8.tar.gz -C trec_eval

And finally, I ran the setup.py with the install option:
python setup.py install

